# Latex: remove space completely after a period

Tags: latex

I would need to insert the following text 'pENN.AAV.CamKII 0.4.Cre.SV40' into my thesis. However, latex applies a double space after each period. I already figured that .\ reduces these to a single space each. However, I want the spaces to be completely removed.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like some sort of variable name, so you could input it with

```
\verb|pENN.AAV.CamKII 0.4.Cre.SV40|
```